# Throwing a custom exception inside try catch

Tags: c#, exception

If I have some code inside a big try catch which eventually catches an `OracleException` and a general `Exception` then I can't throw any custom exception inside the try catch can I, as it gets caught by the general `Exception`.

What am I supposed to do in this instance?

Thanks

```
try
{
    // some code
    if(a==b)
    {
        throw new MyCustomException(ex);
    }
}
catch(OracleException ex)
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I see other people answers, I think the question is not completely clear... Can you rephrase it a little bit or add a bit of code to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: The accepted answer will work, but you should nevertheless try to find away of removing the "catch (Exception ex)".  It is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to throw a custom exception that **isn't** caught by the catch-all `Exception` block?

If this is the case, then try this:

```
try
{
    throw new MyCustomException();
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    // Handle me...
}
catch (MyCustomException)
{
    // Important: NOT `throw ex` (to preserve the stack trace)
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle me...
}
```

Any exception of type `MyCustomException` will be caught by the second `catch` (rather than by the 3rd `catch`) and then rethrown.

Note that it's generally bad practice to do `catch (Exception)` - this is a good example of why. I definitely suggest that rather than doing the above, you simply refactor so that you are no longer catching `Exception`, which would be a far neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
try
{
       ...    
}
catch()
{
       throw new Execption("I'M A NEW EXCEPTION")
}
finally
{
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply add a `catch` clause with your custom exception?

```
try
{
    //Lots of code
}
catch (OracleException)
{   
}
catch (MyCustomException)
{
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: you should not catch an exception in the same method its thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
catch(OracleException ex)
    {
     throw new MyCustomException(
                  "MyCustomEX error: Unable to ......", ex);
    }
```